# Directional derivative of a piecewise defined function $f(x,y)=\frac {x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given
$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac {x^2y}{x^4+y^2} & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 
 0& (x,y)=(0,0) 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I need to calculate the directional derivative at the point (0,0) in the direction making an angle of $30^{\circ}$ with the positive $x$ axis.

Does this derivative even exist? How show I treat this problem?

Comment: Somewhat related question (involving the same function): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167429/continuity-and-partial-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directional derivative in the direction $(h_x,h_y)$ (with $h_y \neq 0$) at $(0,0)$ is given
by $df((0,0),(h_x,h_y)) = \lim_{t \to 0} { f(th_x,t h_y) -f(0,0) \over t} = \lim_{t \to 0} { t^3 h_x^2h_y \over t^4 h_x^4 + t^2 h_y^2}$.

It is straightforward to see that the limit is zero in all cases (look at $h_y=0$ and $h_y \neq 0$ separately).

**Old incorrect answer**: (Thanks to @user61681 for catching that.)

The directional derivative in the direction $(h_x,h_y)$ (with $h_y \neq 0$) at $(0,0)$ is given
by $df((0,0),(h_x,h_y)) = \lim_{t \to 0} { f(th_x,t h_y) -f(0,0) \over t} = \lim_{t \to 0} { t^2 h_x^2h_y \over t^4 h_x + t^2 h_y^2} = {h_x^2 \over h_y}$.

If $(h_x,h_y)$ is in the direction given, we have
$(h_x,h_y) = \lambda ({\sqrt{3} \over 2},{1 \over 2})$ for some $\lambda>0$, and
so $df((0,0),\lambda ({\sqrt{3} \over 2},{1 \over 2})) = {3 \over 2} \lambda$.

Comment: So I have to use the definition here, rather than the nice $\nabla f\cdot (cos30, sin30)$?

Comment: As the other answer points out, $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, so you cannot use that approach. When the function is restricted to a line through the origin, however, it is differentiable and this is the directional derivative.

Comment: I think the other answer doesn't exist anymore.
Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a mistake in what you wrote- you didn't divide by t.
The answer I got is $\frac 3 2$

Comment: @Whyka: Nice catch.

Comment: @Whyka: The directional derivative also depends on the length of the $(h_x,h_y)$, if the length is $1$ then your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's why I took $h_x=\cos(30)$, $h_y=\sin(30)$

Comment: There seems a mistake in the calculation. What is value of f(thx,thy)? The power of t in in numerator should be t^3 but it is taken as t^2. Also the power of hx should be 4 in denominator in the same step. So the directional derivative is 0.

Comment: @user61681 Thanks for catching that. The answer is totally wrong. Will fix. How embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. It was just calculation, not the conceptual mistake...